# Shiny DT "rows_selected" and "rows_all" are deprecated?

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I developed a Shine app which uses "*input$TABLE_NAME_rows_all*" and "*input$TABLE_NAME_rows_selected*" intensively. 
After upgrading DT package this functions does not work. I have checked DT documentation at https://rstudio.github.io/DT/shiny.html and seems that these had been deprecated, whith no clear replace for the "rows_all" option.

First question: is there any solution for this?
Second question: (if first fails) can I run an app with a certain DT version and other apps in same server with the latest DT package?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the link that you have provided it doesn't look like those functions have been depreciated. Chapter 2.1.1 refers to input$tableId_rows_selected to get the selected rows. Chapter 2.2 DataTables Information refers to input$tableId_rows_all to get all the rowas after filtering.

But take a look at this blog post about the release of the new version of DT,
especially this part:

For tables in the server-side processing mode (the default mode for tables in Shiny), the selected row indices are integers instead of characters (row names) now. This is for consistency with the client-side mode (which returns integer indices). In many cases, it does not make much difference if you index an R object with integers or names, and we hope this will not be a breaking change to your Shiny apps.

The blog post is [here](https://blog.rstudio.org/2016/08/09/a-new-version-of-dt-0-2-on-cran/)

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks. The blog explained what I needed. You are right. Functions were not deprecated, but functionality was modified.